# zxing fragment not working

Tags: android, fragment, zxing

I am trying to customize `SimpleStretchedActivity` in `zxingfragmentlib-master` project.

Here is `activity_stretchd_sample.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:name="com.welcu.android.zxingfragmentlibsample.SampleFragment"
    android:id="@+id/scanner_fragment"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    tools:layout="@layout/capture"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:id="@+id/layout_content"
        android:background="#FFF"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Fragment"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:textColor="#000"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is `SampleStretchedActivity.java`:

```
   package com.welcu.android.zxingfragmentlibsample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.welcu.android.zxingfragmentlib.BarCodeScannerFragment;

/**
 * Created by joyarzun on 4/8/14.
 */
public class SampleStretchedActivity extends Activity {
  boolean torchState = false;

  Button mToggleButton;
  LinearLayout layoutContent;
  BarCodeScannerFragment mScannerFragment;

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(com.welcu.android.zxingfragmentlibsample.R.layout.activity_stretched_sample);

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    mScannerFragment = (BarCodeScannerFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.scanner_fragment);

    layoutContent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_content);

    final ViewTreeObserver observer = layoutContent.getViewTreeObserver();

    observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
      @Override
      public void onGlobalLayout() {
        // We're assuming that the other layout is under the scanner
        int activityWidth = layoutContent.getWidth();
        int activityHeight = findViewById(R.id.scanner_fragment).getHeight();

        int usableWidth = layoutContent.getWidth();
        int usableHeight = activityHeight - layoutContent.getHeight();

        int desiredHeight = (int) (usableHeight * 0.8);
        int desiredWidth = (int) (usableWidth * 0.75);

        Rect framingRect = new Rect(
            (usableWidth - desiredWidth) / 2, // left
            (usableHeight - desiredHeight) / 2, // top
            (usableWidth - desiredWidth) / 2 + desiredWidth, // right
            (usableHeight - desiredHeight) / 2 + desiredHeight// bottom
        );
        Log.v("RECT", "left: " + framingRect.left + " top: " + framingRect.top + " right: " + framingRect.right + " bottom: " + framingRect.bottom + " activityHeight: " + activityHeight + " activitiWidth: " + activityWidth);
        mScannerFragment.setFramingRect(framingRect);
      }
    });

//    mToggleButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_flash);
//    mToggleButton.setOnClickListener(createToggleFlashListener());

  }

  private View.OnClickListener createToggleFlashListener() {
    return new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        torchState = !torchState;
        mScannerFragment.setTorch(torchState);
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Here is `SimpleFragment.java`:

```
package com.welcu.android.zxingfragmentlibsample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.zxing.Result;
import com.welcu.android.zxingfragmentlib.BarCodeScannerFragment;

/**
 * Created by mito on 9/17/13.
 */
public class SampleFragment extends BarCodeScannerFragment {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.setmCallBack(new IResultCallback() {
            @Override
            public void result(Result lastResult) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Scan: " + lastResult.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    public SampleFragment() {

    }
}
```

My only change is that I've changed layout_height in inner LinearLayout from 227dp to 350dp. The original code works fine but with this little change my fragment cannot scan any barcode and toast it.

What's the problem? I really need your help

Thanks

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention it. When a barcode is scanned I simply shows it as a toast message.

Comment: OK, but then we still have to know what exactly "cannot" means. Is an exception thrown? Does something not run that otherwise would? If so, what exactly? Something like that.

Comment: No exception at all. I can see red line and yellow circles appearing and disappearing over and over. But nothing is shown as toast meaning that result method never get called. See my edit for SimpleFragment.